# asterisk restrict outgoing number

Tags: asterisk

i have a usb 3g dongle that i use to make/receive calls. i am making calls with the following:

```
exten => _9X.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle800/${EXTEN:1},120,KT)
exten => _9X.,n,Hangup(${HANGUPCAUSE})
```

the provider uses #31# to restrict caller ID so i would like to make use of that and i did try:

```
exten => _9X.,1,Dial(Dongle/dongle800/**#31#**${EXTEN:1},120,KT)
exten => _9X.,n,Hangup(${HANGUPCAUSE})
```

the problem is when i dial 9 and then the number, the provider responds that the format of the dialing is wrong.
Just for testing i inserted this sim card to an ordinary mobile phone and i did try to dial #31# and then the number and it worked fine.
any ideas on how to solve it please?

Comment: What are the `**` for in `**#31#**`? Don't you want to dial `#31#` followed by number?

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk pattern matching(described in ALL asterisk books).

```
X - match any digit ( 0-9)
```

So 9X never match your #31#,sorry

Comment: thanks a lot for the reply. so what is the solution to the problem, please? will the _9#31#X. work?

Comment: Asterisk desgined for people who attempting do-it-yourself. So just TRY.

Comment: i did TRY and it does not work. That's why i asked. Anyhow, do you have any ideas, please?

Comment: not gooign do your work for you. Read about patterns.